# _chdir() not changing directories c++

Tags: c++, directory

I'm making a program to tell me if I changed my directories successfully.  However that is not working. I went through debugger mode and from what i can tell the program is just looking through the files in my visual studios project folder c:\Users#'s\blablabla-----
I want to find dir1 which is a folder on my desktop (and this dir could be anywhere)
here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <direct.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <cstring>
#include "functions.h"

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char**argv)
    {

        int i = 1;
        if (argc < 2)
        {
            cout << "no command line arguments given" << endl;

        }


for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{


    if (_chdir(argv[i]) == 0)
    {
        cout << "Program changed directories successfully" << endl;

    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to change to the directory " << argv[i] << endl;

 }
}
```

Comment: 1) What is the value returned by _chdir when it isn't successful?
2) Instead of hiding the name behind argv[i], how about hard-coding a directory you know exists and seeing if that works?

Comment: The value is not 0.  If i do "c:\\User\\id#\\Desktop" The program changed files successfully. What I have my program find is c:\\dir1 is that too broad?

Comment: I know the value is not 0.  What *is* the value?  The return value will tell you what the problem is.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7fwze1.aspx

Comment: So did you read the link as to what to do when you get a -1 return value?  Did you check to see what `errno` is?  The documentation for functions doesn't just tell you what the function does, but also tells you what to do when an error occurs.

Comment: Yes I did read it. I understand that it returned a -1 because the path could not be found. If i give it a path then it finds it successfully. But i dont know what that path is going to be all i know is c:\\dir1

Comment: Does the directory exist? Do you have read permission in it? What value is `errno`?

Comment: yes. yes. -1 When i use in_buffer = _getcwd(NULL, 0); It gives me the path to my project folder for visual studios.  Could the problem be that my program is not looking around my computer. just in that folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to find dir1 which is a folder on my desktop (and this dir
>   could be anywhere)

The `_chdir` function does not search all over your computer for a directory. It changes to exactly the directory you specify. If you pass `c:\\dir1`, then it tries to change to the directory `c:\\dir1`: The `dir1` directory in the root of your C: drive. If you want to search for any directory on the computer called `dir1`, you need to perform the search yourself.